# C++ current time -> two digits

Tags: c++, date, time, digits, ctime

I display the current date/time via

```
#include <ctime>
time_t sec = time(NULL);
tm* curTime = localtime(&sec);    
cout << "Date: " <<  curTime->tm_mday << "." << curTime->tm_mon << "." << curTime->tm_year+1900 << endl;
cout << "Time: " << curTime->tm_hour << ":" << curTime->tm_min << ":" << curTime->tm_sec << endl;
```

Actually it displays e.g.

```
Date: 4.10.2016
Time: 9:54:0
```

I got 2 problems here:

1. I want two digits for both, the date (day and month) and the time (hour, minute and second). So it should display 04.10.2016 and 09:54:00
2. Today, it displays 24.10.2016 but today it's the 24.11.2016. Why does it display october and not november? The Linux-clock shows the time correctly.

Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: 2. Months are indexed from 0 to 11 (0 is January and 11 is December) so you have to +1 to the number

Comment: Which C++ standard do you use?

Comment: I'm using -std=c++0x since -std=c++11 is not activated somehow on my computer (and I do not have the rights to change it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use manipulators for printing.
   in printf("%02d", curTime->tm_hour)
   in cout, you can use,
   std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << curTime->tm_hour.
2. tm_mon is from 0 to 11. So you should use tm_mon+1 for printing.

Comment: Great! Thanks...Didn't think of setfill(0) :)

Answer (score 0):

For your formatting, try [std::strftime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime)

Answer (score 0):

1. There are several ways.

If you use C++11 and your compiler has std::put_time() from the iomanip header implemented (though it is not your case unfortunately):

```
std::cout << "Date: " << std::put_time(curTime, "%d.%m.%Y") << std::endl;
std::cout << "Time: " << std::put_time(curTime, "%H:%M:%S") << std::endl;
```

If you use an older compiler version (your case):

```
std::string to_string(const char* format, tm* time) {
    std::vector<char> buf(100, '\0');
    buf.resize(std::strftime(buf.data(), buf.size(), format, time));
    return std::string(buf.begin(), buf.end());
}
std::cout << "Date: " << to_string("%d.%m.%Y", curTime) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Time: " << to_string("%H.%M.%S", curTime) << std::endl;
```

2. As user7777777 mentioned, tm_mon = 0..11.